# Difference in different vgg16 objects

Tags: keras, vgg-net

I am going through vgg16 model and saw this:

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
```

and

```
model = VGG16()
```

1. What is the difference between the above two?
2. Does the second initialization also load weights in the imported vgg16 model?
3. How can I just import the vgg16 without loading the weights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between these two since according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) the `weights` argument by default is set to `'imagenet'`:

```
keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
```

Therefore if you don't set this argument when instantiating the `VGG16` class, it would be set to `'imagenet'` by default and therefore the ImageNet weights will be loaded.

However, if you like to just load the VGG16 model without any pre-trained weights, you can pass `weights=None` when instantiating `VGG16` class. Read the [documentation on VGG16](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) for more info about the arguments.

Comment: How can I just import the vgg16 without loading the weights ?

Comment: @ajaysingh Update my answer (last paragraph).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Is the last paragraph ambiguous? :)